# Trouble with replace() and § JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, replace

I am trying to figure a problem which leaves me scratching my head when I try to replace § with its ul code it seems the replace() function does not pick it.

here's code: `var replaced = str.replace(/%s/g, "<span style='width:15px;height:10px;'>&#160;</span>").replace(/§/g, "u/00a7")`

the %s works fine so I think its the double s itself not functioning properly. Thanks

**Solution I used:** in the end I couldn't get the double s to replace so in the end I went with this : `&#92;u00a7` and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"u/00a7"` is exactly those characters in JavaScript. You probably meant `"\u00a7"`. But replacing `§` with `"\u00a7"` is pointless, they're the same character. If you meant to replace it with an HTML entity, that would be `&#167;`:

```js
var s = "See §123";

// Replace
s = s.replace(/§/g, "&#167;");

// Display WITHOUT letting the browser interpret the entity
var p = document.createElement('pre');
if ('textContent' in p) {
  p.textContent = "Not interpreted: " + s;
} else {
  p.innerText = "Not interpreted: " + s;
}
document.body.appendChild(p);

// Display WITH the browser interpreting the entity (so we'll see §)
p = document.createElement('pre');
p.innerHTML = "Interpreted: " + s;
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

...but just having § literally should be fine. Even if you were having character encoding issues (and if you were, you'd want to solve them rather than do this), § is the same character in all of the popular encodings...

Comment: Yes sorry thats what i mean but it still doesn't fix the S not replacing.

Comment: @Scar: Yes, it does. In your code, you'll find the replacement in `replaced` (not `str`). Of course, if you output that to something that interprets the string as HTML, the thing interpreting it will show you §, because it interprets the character entity (that's why I used `textContent`/`innerText` above instead).

Comment: I have modified the code a bit and not it seems to not work here is the code http://pastebin.com/PX2nBgAv it is extracting data passed on from another page and i am wondering if the url formatting is the problem as the double S is appearing like %A7

Comment: @Scar: If you're decoding something from a URI, you use `decodeURIComponent`, not `replace`.